# Kendo Ui Slider with Custom Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to skip a value in a Kendo Ui Slider.

Let's say, I have a slider with minimum 1 and maximum 5.

the slider would show the following values : 1   2  3  4  5

I need the Slider to have the following values : 1  3  4  5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Having the values mean showing 1, 3, 4 and 5 values or might it show value 2 as well but not accept you to select it? Avoid selecting it is possible, but skipping it I don't think you can.

Comment: It can only be achieved after you select the value to change it to the required value. check the events page to know more about how to change the value after selecting. https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/slider/events